# Stardict main window is hidden

Tags: ubuntu

I use Stardict in Ubuntu 12.04 and everything was fine.

But recently the main window (with settings, vocabularies etc) stops displaying for me. I have tried everything, but this window is not showing anywhere, thus I cannot change settings of the program (I want to remap key bindings).

I think it's an option "Hide main window on startup" or something like that, I have turned it ON.

Could you help me please to display the main window or at least point to configuration file of stardict to reset this option?

Answer (score 1):

Open `gnome-terminal`, enter `stardict - Lookup words` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The main graphical window will open now. Untick the main window's *hide* option.

Answer (score 0):

edit configuration, set `hide_on_startup` to **true** (restart stardict!)

```
$ gedit ~/.gconf/apps/stardict/preferences/main_window/%gconf.xml

...
<entry name="hide_on_startup" mtime="1415306042" type="bool" value="true"/>
...
```

Or start main window on gnome-terminal:

```
$ stardict &
```

If no window opens, stardict do not running befor.
Now try again:

```
$ stardict
```

Now you can configure...

If you close this main window, stardict will be exit complete!
using to hide window:

```
$ stardict -h
```

hint: activate scan